# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrading Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) shows unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, package-management, hardware-enablement-stack

When upgrading from to the new Hardware Enablement Stack manually using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

This error comes up:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5feedback5 : Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What could be the cause and how can I solve this?

System:

```
Linux sandsturm 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP
  Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: did you happen to use `intel-linux-graphics-installer` at some point? If you don't remember than this could show `apt-cache policy libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri`

Comment: yes, i did. what does this change?

Comment: It makes it impossible to upgrade to the new mesa hwe stack. What you would need to do is replace most of the packages that were acquired from Intel with the current Trusty repo versions. While the versions in trusty-updates & trusty-security are the same the package names aren't the same package names. I give an example here but may not cover your complete situation http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2265453&p=13232856#post13232856

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/588558/unable-to-upgrade-trusty-14-04-1-to-the-14-04-2-hwe/588606#588606  Use this answer as an example of what to do

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, and this worked for me:

1. I installed the 14.04 (trusty) versions of those same packages first:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-trusty
   ```
2. Once I installed those, I was able to run the [command to upgrade the enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Desktop):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
   ```
3. Lastly, a bit of cleanup:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```

**Edit:**

After following the above steps, Steam tried to install a couple packages (libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 and libgl1-mesa-glx:i386) and they were failing. I was able to fix it easily:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

I'll have to remember that pattern for packages in the future if they fail installing/upgrading (try adding `-lts-utopic` to the package name).